# Are $l^p$ and $(l^q)'$ canonically isomorphic or just isomorphic?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, isometry, dual-spaces

As we know from basic functional analysis, the sequence spaces $l^p$ and $(l^q)'$ are isometrically isomorphic.

Are they considered to be canonically isomorphic or just isomorphic?

Based on the replies [to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3203028/), I'd guess that they are indeed canonically isomorphic because the map between them doesn't seem to require a choice of a basis. But I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual (isometric) isomorphism between $\ell^p$ and $(\ell^q)^*$, where $1/p+1/q=1$, is given by
$$\Phi:\ell^p\to(\ell^q)^*$$
$$\ell^p\ni(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty:=x\mapsto\Phi(x):\ell^q\to\mathbb{C}$$
where
$$\Phi(x)(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_ny_n $$
for all $(y_n)\in\ell^q$.

Based on the discussion in the linked post, since there were no "choices" involved in the definition of this isomorphism, we can say that this is a canonical isomorphism. Also, as mentioned already, this term does not have a precise meaning, so we usually say that something is "canonical" when it is "expected" to be defined in this way. This map is definitely of that form, the reason behind that being measure theory:

We can actually see $\ell^p$ as the $L^p$ space of $\mathbb{N}$ with the counting measure and $(x_n)\in\ell^p$ is nothing but a function $f$ such that $\int|f|^p<\infty$. We send such an element of $L^p$ to the linear functional $g\mapsto\int f\cdot g$, which is the most "canonical" thing to do. By the famous H"older inequality, this is bounded on $L^q$, which again in our case is identified with $\ell^q$. This is precisely what our map $\Phi$ does.

Comment: This isomorphism looks a bit like an inner product. Can this also be seen through the lens of the Riesz representation theorem? (although I know that the theorem assumes a Hilbert space and $l^p$ is only Hilbert for $p=2$). Thanks +1

Comment: @Leo Well, I don't think so. Also, I wouldn't say that it looks like an inner product; maybe you have this impression because you are thinking of the Hilbert space $\ell^2$ and its inner product, but in general there is no reason to expect that, or at least that's what I think.